# Magento 2 : Testing External API Integration

Tags: magento2.3

I have read magento documentation on how to integrate external API(https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ext-best-practices/tutorials/create-integration-with-api.html), but it has no info on how to execute the script and get the response. This might be silly question but I cannot find how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following steps :

1. Create one custom module.
2. Implement the code properly there mention into the URL.
3. Enable the module into the magento2.
4. Create one script file into magento2 root.
5. Create the Object Of your class and call the `doRequest` method with proper parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop Magento2 integration manually or programmatically.
In the first case, you need to Go to System -> Integrations Menu, choose the option - add new integration, enter the integration name, make sure that the access to API resources is granted, activate the integration. After that, you will be able to perform API requests.
In the second case, you have to create the module file structure, define your module configuration file etc/module.xml, add your module’s composer.json file, create a registration.php file, define the integration and install the module to run the setup scripts. A great article that may help you: https://www.beehexa.com/devdocs/how-to-create-an-integration-in-magento-2/.
In case if you have a lot of difficulties related to Magento2 integration, you can always use some special solution like API2Cart.